# Не получается @Autowired JavaMailSender Возвращает null

Tags: java, spring-boot, javamail

Доброго времени суток.

Пишу не большую программку по рассылке почты и на самом начале столкнулся с проблемой.

Когда:

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

public void send() {
   MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();  ---- Вот тут NullPointerExeption;
```

Spring-Boot properties:

```
#email property
spring.mail.host=mail.ukraine.com.ua
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.username=eugen@karpkoi.com.ua
spring.mail.password=test
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
```

Пробовал создавать Bean в файле, но результат тот-же.

Как победить этот упорный Spring. 
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: проверьте, что прописан контекст и что класс помечен аннотаций, например @Service.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Спасибо, это все есть, но не работает. Хотя по контексту подскажите что вы имеете ввиду, я просто в точке старта приложения добавил @ ComponentScan  с путем к конфигам.

Comment: да, я имел ввиду что-то вроде ComponentScan. посмотрите так же в лог - возможно там будут ошибки инициализации bean.